# I need Javascript function to disable enter key

Tags: javascript

I need to use JS function to disable enter key. I'm currently facing an issue with my Spring form

```
<form:textarea path="name" onkeypress="return noenter()"
```

here is the function I currently using

```
<script> function noenter() {   alert("Testing");
    return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); 
    } </script>
```

for some reason, the alert is working when I press on Enter key, but still facing same exception

> HTTP Status 415 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The server refused this
>   request because the request entity is
>   in a format not supported by the
>   requested resource for the requested
>   method (). Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Comment: `window.event` is not cross-browser I think. It's an IE thing...

Comment: Is there something peculiar about the textareas you are using?  Typically, an HTML textarea element turns ENTER into newlines, rather than submitting the form, no javascript needed.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

Markup:

```
<form:textarea path="name" onkeypress="return noenter(event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function noenter(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    return key !== 13; 
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fj3Mh/

Comment: @Ali Check the event type and key value. Place this right before the return statement: `alert('e.type: ' + e.type + '; key: ' + key);` - it should alert "keypress" and a number. I've updated my answer with a **live demo**.

Answer (score 1):

you need to address this in the keyup and keydown event. The browser uses the enter key independent of the actual web page. So you will need to stop event propagation at the keyup or keydown event. By the time the keypress event has been emitted the browser itself has received it and there is no way to keep it from processing. This is specific to the enter key and a few others. Character keys such as 'a' and 'b' do not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function stopRKey(evt) { 
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
} 

document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for the questions that already have answers.