# OnClientClick triggered when enter pressed in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onclientclick

I have a form with runat="server" and inside it I have two elements :

```
<form runat="server">
  <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="doSomething();" />
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="hello" />
</form>
```

My problem is when I press enter while the cursor inside the textbox the `doSomething` function runs. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent ASP.NET textbox within a form from submitting the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267522/prevent-asp-net-textbox-within-a-form-from-submitting-the-form)

Comment: possibly you need set [TextMode to MultiLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `UseSubmitBehavior` to false.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="doSomething();" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```